# Forward parameters to another method

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

The method `on` from jQuery has different signatures:

```
# Signature 1
$('.container').on 'click', -> ...
# Signature 2
$('.container').on 'click', 'button', -> ...
```

I am building a method in a class, and I would like to forward its parameters to the `on` method, using the proper signature

```
obj = new MyObject $('.container')

# Uses signature 1
obj.on 'mouseenter', -> ...
# Uses signature 2
obj.on 'mouseleave', 'button', -> ...
```

What I built so far uses only the first signature.

```
class MyObject
    constructor: (@el) ->
    on: (event, callbacks) => @el.on event, callbacks
```

How could I modify my class, so that it can use both signatures?

Answer (score -1):

You could achieve that by using 'Splats':

```
class MyObject
    constructor: (@el) ->
    on: (events..., last) => @el.on event, last for event in events
```

This one method will actually cover both scenarios at once.